# How to use a global temporary table in a function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

so I have a function that takes in 3 IN parameters (hour, date, code)
 and returns a number.

My function code is below:

```
create or replace FUNCTION     get_max_value    (rhr       NUMBER,
                                                 rdate    VARCHAR2,
                                                 rcode      VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   rvalue_day   NUMBER;
--
BEGIN
   SELECT MAX (v.value)
     INTO rvalue_day
     FROM table v
          JOIN rel_table_1 sv ON (v.value_id = sv.value_id)
          JOIN look_up_table ff ON (sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id)
    WHERE     v.date = rdate
          AND v.code = rcode
          AND v.hr_num = rhr
          AND (v.code = 'PASS' OR v.code IS NULL);
   RETURN rvalue_day;
END;
```

Because of performance issues, I am trying to use a global temporary table that grabs the values (v.value) and the primary_identifier associated to it (value_Id). My code is below:

```
with  table_c as 
(
  select value, value_id 
    from table where date = rdate 
     AND code = rcode 
     AND hr_num = rhr
 )
select MAX (v.value)
     FROM table_c v
          JOIN rel_table_1 sv ON (v.value_id = sv.value_id)
          JOIN look_up_table ON (sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id)
    WHERE     ff.code_desc = rcode;
```

Is there a way I can incorporate the above method into a function so that it can accept values for multiple parameters? I currently have a stored proc that is trying to derive a value by inserting 3 values into those 3 parameters...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Because of performance issues ....` better create a view instead of this function, you will get 40~50-fold increase in a speed, practically without any effort. Yes - 4000%~5000% it's not mistake.

Comment: hmmm what is -4000%-5000%? and thanks for the suggestion! not sure why I haven't thought of that before!

Comment: It's a simple calculation - 40 times faster * 100% = 4000% faster. A bigger number makes a bigger impression, although it's the same number but only with % sign.

Comment: By "global temporary table" do you mean the Common Table Expression in your second query (i.e., the `WITH` clause)? Because the optimizer is going to rewrite your query no matter what you do, these may wind up being equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is not an answer to your question "how can I optimize this function".**
I'm going to show you that the very idea of using a function can be a reason of your performance problems - and I'am guessing that this is the case in your case.

---

Please look at the below very simple case:

```
create table ttest as 
select * from all_objects
fetch first 10000 rows only;

create index ttest_ix on ttest(object_type);

create or replace function get_max(p_object_type varchar)
return number
is
  ret_val number;
begin
  select max(object_id) into ret_val
  from ttest
  where object_type = p_object_type;
  return ret_val;
end;
/

create or replace view get_max_view as
select object_type, max(object_id) as max_id
from ttest
group by object_type
;
```

The view `get_max_view` is an equivalent of the function `get_max`, you can use both for example in this way in queries:

```
select object_id, object_type, get_max(object_type) as max_id
from ttest;

select object_id, object_type, 
       (select max_id from get_max_view x where x.object_type = t.object_type) as max_id
from ttest t;
```

---

And now please examine the case where both the above queries are run against 10000 records - to do so I nest both queries as subqueries, and caclulate a sum of all their results:

```
set timings on;

select sum(max_id)
from (
    select object_id, object_type, get_max(object_type) as max_id
    from ttest
);

SUM(MAX_ID)
-----------
  214087478

Elapsed: 00:00:11.764

select sum(max_id)
from (
    select object_id, object_type, 
           (select max_id from get_max_view x where x.object_type = t.object_type) as max_id
    from ttest t
);

SUM(MAX_ID)
-----------
  214087478

Elapsed: 00:00:00.011
```

Please examine the times - 11.76 seconds vs. 11 miliseconds.
This is over 1000 times faster - **100000% faster** !!!
This is why I suggested you in the comment to replace this functin by the view, because this is the most probably cause of your performance issues, and trying to optimize this function is probably the wrong way.

Comment: Well, this is kind of *unfair*. It would be interesting to see the result if you first ran the second query (which selects from a view), and then the one that uses the function. Or, at least, run both of them several times. Caching and stuff ...

Comment: @Littlefoot just copy and paste this case to your system, change the order of queries and click `run`,  I leave this test case to you

Comment: Well, I did, 11gXE on a laptop. 9 miliseconds vs. 3.4 seconds, which is still WAY faster, but not that much. (BTW, I upvoted your answer ages ago as I agree with everything you said).